# possible to specify field enclosure in psql command line?

Tags: postgresql, psql

In psql if I have a field separator of ",", but there are commas in some fields, is it possible to specify a field enclosure character? I have looked through the documentation but I can't find it.

example:

```
psql -h my_server -U my_user -d my_db -f sql_in/my_sql.sql -o sql_out/my_sql_out.csv -A -F','
```

-A will turn off the table formatting, -F specifies the field separator

If I have a row that looks like

```
id  types
1   zebra, lion, cat
2   horse
```

I want it to output to csv like:

```
1,"zebra, lion, cat"
2,"horse"
```

Comment: Use `copy`, see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61636282/330315

Comment: Wow, it's hard to believe they left that out of the command line version. Thank you!

Comment: No idea what you mean with "left that out", the solution using `copy` will work "*with the command line*"

Comment: I meant command line in the sense of not using the psql shell. I meant straight from the bash command line like in my example in the original question.

Comment: You just need to replace your query in `my_sql.sql` with `copy (your query here...) to stdout` and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v12, `psql` introduced the `--csv` option.  However, it still seems like the wrong tool for the job.  You should use COPY or \copy instead (probably still invoked through psql)